# Pandas DataFrame ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is the code:

```
a = {
    "Date": ["2020-01-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-03", "2020-01-03", "2020-01-03", "2020-01-03"],
    "Count": [39, 43, 30, 27, 6, 7, 8, 3, 11, 16, 15, 19]
}

b = {
    "Date_used": ["2020-01-01", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-03"],
    "Value": [39, 7, 5, 12]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(a)
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(b)
df2["Date_used"] = pd.to_datetime(df2["Date_used"])

df2["In df?"] = df[["Date", "Count"]].isin(df2[["Date_used","Value"]])
```

I am trying create a column in *df2* that will look for a row in *df* that matches its respective row and if one is found, return True otherwise return False. The ideal result for *df2* would be the following:

| Date | Value | In df? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 39 | True |
| 2020-01-02 | 7 | True |
| 2020-01-02 | 5 | False |
| 2020-01-03 | 12 | False |

As you can see, the first two rows in *df2* have a match in *df* but the second two don't.

I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../b.py", line 22, in <module>
    df2["In df?"] = df[["Date", "Count"]].isin(df2[["Date_used","Value"]])
  File "...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3163, in __setitem__
    self._set_item(key, value)
  File "...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3243, in _set_item
    NDFrame._set_item(self, key, value)
  File "C:\Users\Ruairidh Livingstone\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3829, in _set_item
    self._mgr.insert(len(self._info_axis), key, value)
  File "...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 1203, in insert
    block = make_block(values=value, ndim=self.ndim, placement=slice(loc, loc + 1))
  File "...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py", line 2732, in make_block
    return klass(values, ndim=ndim, placement=placement)
  File "...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py", line 142, in __init__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1
```

I think that part of the problem is that the lengths of *df* and *df2* are different however I am unsure of how to solve this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The code you shared does not work, you are using the column `"Date_used"` in `df2` but that column does not exist (you have a column named `"Date"` though). Maybe you have copied your code wrongly? also please include the full error traceback

Comment: @MatteoZanoni yep my bad, should be fixed now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option via `merge`:

```
df2 = df2.merge(df, left_on=df2.columns.to_list(), right_on=df.columns.to_list(), how='left', indicator='In_df').drop(
    df.columns.to_list(), 1).assign(In_df=lambda x: x['In_df'].map({'both': True, 'left_only': False}))
```

Output:

```
   Date_used  Value  In_df
0 2020-01-01     39   True
1 2020-01-02      7   True
2 2020-01-02      5  False
3 2020-01-03     12  False
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `pd.merge` in this way

```
df2['In df?'] = df2.merge(df.drop_duplicates(), left_on=['Date','Value'], \
                    right_on=['Date','Count'], how='left', indicator=True)

df2['In df?'] = np.where(df_all['_merge']=='both', True, False)
```

or with map

```
df2['In df?'] = df2.merge(df.drop_duplicates(), left_on=['Date','Value'],\
                          right_on=['Date','Count'], how='left', indicator=True)\
                         .map({'both': True, 'left_only': False})
```

Output

```
    Date         Value  In df?
0   2020-01-01   39     True
1   2020-01-02   7      True
2   2020-01-02   5      False
3   2020-01-03   12     False
```